How can I use JSTL in my Spring boot project
I wanna use JSTL in my spring boot project for view data in database mysql. I tried use dependency in pom.xml but when i use this tag <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="https://jakarta.ee/jstl/core" %>, this is error. I used JSTL Jakarta version 2.0.0 and JSTL Jakarta Servlet API 6.0.0 but this not work. Can anyone help me please !!
Can anyone help me please !!enter image description hereenter image description here

Tags for jstl 2.0 can be found here

What is the error's message?

Spring Boot war Run In Tomcat or Spring Boot jar ?

Spring Boot 3.x base on Jakarta EE 10

Jakarta Servlet 6.0
Jakarta Standard Tag Library 3.0
Spring Boot 3.x
JDK 17

pom.xml
for JSTL
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

for Database

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
</dependency>

application.properties
src/main/resources/application.properties
spring.application.name=hello-jsp
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/yourDB
spring.datasource.username=your-user
spring.datasource.password=your-password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

HelloJDBCJSPController.java
package com.example;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import javax.sql.DataSource;
import java.util.Map;

@Controller
public class HelloJDBCJSPController {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/helloDS", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView getDataSource(Map<String, Object> model) {
        System.out.println("HelloJDBCJSPController >>>> dataSource = " + dataSource);
        model.put("dataSource", dataSource);
        // /WEB-INF/jsp/index-tag-003.jsp
        return new ModelAndView("index-tag-003");
    }

}

index-tag-003.jsp
src/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/index-tag-003.jsp
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ page import="javax.sql.DataSource" %>

<%@ taglib uri="jakarta.tags.sql" prefix="sql" %>
<%@ taglib uri="jakarta.tags.core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Taglib 003 Example of sql tag</title>
</head>
<body>

<sql:query dataSource="${requestScope.dataSource}" var="result">
    SELECT * FROM STUDENTS;
</sql:query>

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
    <c:forEach var="row" items="${result.rows}">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${row.id}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${row.name}"/></td>
            <td><c:out value="${row.email}"/></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
</body>
</html>

correct uri is here:
<%@ taglib uri="jakarta.tags.sql" prefix="sql" %>
<%@ taglib uri="jakarta.tags.core" prefix="c" %>

Reference:
https://jakarta.ee/specifications/tags/3.0/jakarta-tags-spec-3.0#multiple-tag-libraries
Functional  URI                     Prefix
----------  ----                    --------
core        jakarta.tags.core       c
sql         jakarta.tags.sql        sql
xml         jakarta.tags.xml        x
I18N        jakarta.tags.fmt        fmt
Functions   jakarta.tags.functions  fn

Spring Boot war run on Tomcat 10.1 Server.

Ref Database MYSQL:
init.sql
CREATE TABLE STUDENTS (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    age INT,
    grade VARCHAR(10),
    email VARCHAR(100),
    enrollment_date DATE
);

INSERT INTO STUDENTS (name, age, grade, email, enrollment_date)
VALUES
('Alice', 20, 'A', 'alice@example.com', '2023-01-15'),
('Bob', 22, 'B', 'bob@example.com', '2023-02-10'),
('Charlie', 21, 'A', 'charlie@example.com', '2023-03-12'),
('David', 23, 'C', 'david@example.com', '2023-04-08'),
('Eva', 20, 'B', 'eva@example.com', '2023-05-05');

